# How to split data from api to get a chart

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, chart.js

I have face a problem to split data that i got from local api and to display it on chart.

I have done this code to get the data from the api

```
this.api.getPerformancePie(username, password).subscribe(Post=>{
        console.log(Post);

for(let Data of Post){
            console.log(Data.Status);
            const series = Data['Status'];

            this.doughnutChart= new Chart(this.doughnutCanvas.nativeElement, {
              type: "doughnut",
              data:{
                labels: [series],
                datasets: [
                  {
                    label: 'Completed',
                    data: [Data.Count],
                  },
                ]
              }
            })

          }
```

and this code is inside my `.html`

```
<ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-title>Overall Schedule Performance</ion-card-title>
  </ion-card-header>
  <ion-card-content>
    <canvas #doughnutCanvas></canvas>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

The output on the doughnut chart supposed to have 5 series. but i only got 1 series and there is no petition to include another 4 series. the output i got is as below

[image]

I hope anyone can show and teach me the proper way to display the data. Also below i attach the data that should been displayed, but it didn't show up

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

All of your code is inside the `for` loop and is being executed five times. So four charts are being created and destroyed with only the fifth one being displayed.

Move your chart creation code outside of the `for` loop, something like this:

```
const series = [],
  counts = [];

for (let Data of Post) {
  series.push(Data.Status);
  counts.push(Data.Count);
}

this.doughnutChart = new Chart(this.doughnutCanvas.nativeElement, {
  type: "doughnut",
  data: {
    labels: series,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Completed',
      data: counts,
    }]
  }
})
```

Note that I haven't run this code so there may be a typo, but it shows the concept of what you need to change to fix the problem. (Next time please post your data as text, *not* a screenshot. Then I could have built a working example here.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the labels and data from the response. You could remove the `for` loop and use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
series = this.Post.map(item => Number(item.Count));
labels = this.Post.map(item => item.Status);
```

Notice the `Number` cast for `item.Count`. It is needed since the response from the API is of string type and the chart only accepts data as a numbers array.

Also you do not need to define `label: 'Completed'` property inside `datasets` since it is defined using `labels` property. Try the following

```js
this.api.getPerformancePie(username, password).subscribe( Post => {
  const series = Post.map(item => Number(item.Count));
  const labels = Post.map(item => item.Status);

  this.doughnutChart = new Chart(this.doughnutCanvas.nativeElement, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: [
        { 
          data: series,
          backgroundColor: ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'turquoise']
        },
      ]
    }
  });
}
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-starter-app-k23eyp)